# Saving grep/sed result in Jenkins file without "" to variable with checking that string not beginnig with comments '//'

Tags: bash, sed, grep, terraform, jenkins-groovy

Saving a result from grep/sed from terraform file to a variable.

```
terraformProjectName = sh(script: "grep -E  '^[^//]*project' *.tf | grep -o '\"[^\"]*\"' | sed -e 's/^\"//' -e 's/\"\$//'", returnStdout:true).trim()
```

As a result, I got a terraformProjectName with the name of a project from *.tf file

Comment: We would need to see the relevant JP code for SCM retrieval and other effects to the retrieved code.

Comment: Code in the bottom part of the text.